# About if __name__= "__main__": method

Tags: python

I am probably missing something really simple.

So here is my code:

```
def test():
    return 'Hello!'

if __name__=="__main__":
    print test()
```

On executing `python module_name.py` there in no output. When I import the module and execute `module_name.test()` I get my the expected output. What am I missing here?

Comment: How did you execute the code without importing?

Comment: *"On executing the code without importing"* Please show us exactly how you're doing this. Also please fix the excessive whitespace (horizontal and vertical) in your code.

Comment: I am using Geany. It has a builtin compile option which executes the command python -m py_compile "module_name.py"

Comment: Nope. That's not how you execute a file in python. You want just `python tst.py` Then it's __name__ will be __main__.

Comment: If that is the *actual indentation* (actually looks like it might have been introduced in an edit?) it won't work because the if block is inside the function.

Comment: @JasonS Fixed the indentation issue. It was the result of an edit.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart using <code>python module_name.py </code>  isn't giving a different outcome. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Why are you continuing to use `<code>` tag instead of `backticks`? Only backticks work in comments. And [thanks should be removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/230282). Just an upvote is enough

Comment: @DBS see here: http://ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/module-name.html